# Class 'Importer' not found patosmack/laravel-excel - laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel, laravel-excel

Actually I want to import an excel file to database using **patosmack/laravel-excel** library. I Followed all these steps given in this [link](https://packagist.org/packages/patosmack/laravel-excel) but in the end I got this error.
I don't know how to fix it. I searched this error every where no answer found.

[image]

Comment: Have you registered `Cyberduck\LaravelExcel\ExcelServiceProvider::class` in providers in `app.php` ?

Comment: yes i did this all...

Comment: Try composer dumpautoload and clear config and cache of your project.

Comment: I left using this **php class**... now I am using `JS Class` for Importing XLS files